# MVC Move Function to Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I have a function called `ToFriendlyUrl` used within a View, but would like to centralise this code by moving it into a class so the functionality can be referenced from other Views.

```
@functions {
    private object ToFriendlyUrl(string urlToEncode)
    {
        var url = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char ch in urlToEncode)
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                case ' ':
                    url.Append('-');
                    break;
                case '&':
                    url.Append("and");
                    break;
                case '\'':
                    break;
                default:
                    if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'))
                    {
                        url.Append(ch);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        url.Append('-');
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return url.ToString();
    }
}
```

The function is called like so `ToFriendlyUrl(content.Title)`.

Could some body please demonstrate how I would construct the new class and then how I would reference the functionality from a View?

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can create HtmlHelper extension:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ToFriendlyUrl(this HtmlHelper helper, string urlToEncode)
    {
        var url = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char ch in urlToEncode)
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                case ' ':
                    url.Append('-');
                    break;
                case '&':
                    url.Append("and");
                    break;
                case '\'':
                    break;
                default:
                    if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'))
                    {
                        url.Append(ch);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        url.Append('-');
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(url.ToString());
    }
}
```

and use it on your views like this:

```
@Html.ToFriendlyUrl(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a class, you can move the function to _Layout, add it to a script block and all views would be able to call it.

You can also move it to a js file and include it in the view where the functionality is required or _Layout can include the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the function in to a Partial view. Then you can render the partial view wherever you want.

good luck